# Resource file in iPhone app problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have an image which is added to the project. In the simulator it appears, but when I build for the device the resource is not included. I also started a new project and nothing. Please help me. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the image file and created a new file with the same image and it works... I think it was a bug of the file...

Answer (score 2):

Please check the extension of image file you are using. This happened with me , I was using .png format in project but file was in .jpeg format

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you copied the image into project, xcode ask to copy the file in project when you drag file in resource. Also check for your file name is correct (check for case sensitive ).

Comment: Yes it is in the project. In the simulator app is there and in the device app is not there.

Comment: Try to delete app from iPhone, delete build quit simulator and run the app again. Also try to delete it and include it again.

Comment: I tried everything, restarted iPhone, comp, deleted, included again, but nothing solved it.